# Lollipop Style Menu Reveal Animation

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

For most of Google's updated Android apps, when the user taps the menu button, the menu reveal animates really nicely. (ie: Chrome and the Google Play app)

I'm using AppCompat's ActionBar and theme. Is there any way to achieve the same effect in my apps?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of animation do you want, reveal circular transition or Navigation drawer-arrow animation?

Comment: I'm looking for the animation where the expanded menu explodes from the original menu item source. ie: see Chrome or Play Store apps.

Comment: In Play store app, there is only Navigation drawer, is that you want?

Comment: In Play Store app, select an app you already have installed and you'll see a menu item in the top right. Its easier to see in Chrome app.